# /dev entries generator Script in Linux Device Driver by Jonathan Corbet

Tags: bash, shell, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I've started studying "Linux Device Drivers 3rd ed" and i am having trouble understanding the syntax of the following script. I know basic shell scripting and can use the awk utility for making basic programs

Q1)/sbin/insmod ./$module.ko $* || exit 1
a)what was the need for stating the full path of insmod?
b)i've use ./ for invoking executable files but never seen ./ in the middle of a command.
c)is $module=scull???
d)what does $* mean?
e)what the double bat for ?

Q2)major=$(awk "\$2= =\"$module\" {print \$1}" /proc/devices)
What are the steps this awk statement goes through to get us the scull devices?
i dont get the double slashes '\' and the double equal sign.

```
#!/bin/sh
module="scull"
device="scull"
mode="664"
# invoke insmod with all arguments we got
# and use a pathname, as newer modutils don't look in . by default
/sbin/insmod ./$module.ko $* || exit 1   
# remove stale nodes   
rm -f /dev/${device}[0-3]   
major=$(awk "\\$2= =\"$module\" {print \\$1}" /proc/devices)
mknod /dev/${device}0 c $major 0
mknod /dev/${device}1 c $major 1
mknod /dev/${device}2 c $major 2
mknod /dev/${device}3 c $major 3
```

Comment: UPDATE: i've downloaded the examples from the orielly's ftp. And the statement in Q2 is a bit changed (no double slashes). 
here is the line:</br>

    major=$(awk "\$2==\"$module\" {print \$1}" /proc/devices)
</br>
i still dont get it though :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1

a) The need to state the full path for insmod because it will always accessible even though you are in location that is not defined in PATH
b) ./something means something is a file located in current path.  ./$module.ko means that file ./scull.ko
c) same as b
d) $* means whatever parameters that you give to the shell script.
e) double pipe (or bat) means OR. It means, insmod the module, or if fail, exit with return value 1

I dont have answer for Q2. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

A1.a: Absolute path for insmod is needed for case when environment not contain $PATH variable or $PATH is not contain "/sbin" path.
A1.b: And where is question? "./" - is just relative path. It use when you need get access to some file object from current directory. In common case in "./" expression the "dot" replace output of $(pwd) command but not it's faster and shorter.
A1.c: yes, in this code module named "scull" will loaded. What question?
A1.d: "$*" is a special shell variable contains all passed to this script parameters.
A1.d: "||" is a logical "or" operator.

I require to read some about bash for example [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/). This guide hepls me some time ago.

Q2:

```
major=$(awk "\\$2= =\"$module\" {print \\$1}" /proc/devices)
```

In this line

```
awk "\\$2= =\"$module\" {print \\$1}" /proc/devices
```

runs as subshell and stdout assigned to "major" variable. In my linux box this awk-command doesn't work due syntax errors, but I recognize here awk-actions. In this case content of /proc/devices parsed and if second word is equal value "module" variable then code in curly brackets will executed. In other words if second word of line is "scull" then print first word of those line. In my linux box this line works fine:

```
major=$(awk "\$2 == \"$module\" {print \$1}" /proc/devices)
```